# Configure only one pod of GitLab Kubernetes agent instead of the default two pods

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to run only one pod of GitLab Kubernetes agent, instead of the default two provided.

I followed [this guide](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/clusters/agent/) and ran this command:

```
helm upgrade --install mycoolagent gitlab/gitlab-agent --namespace mycoolnamespace --create-namespace --set image.tag=v16.1.3 --set config.token=<token> --set config.kasAddress=ws://gitlab.com/-/kubernetes-agent/
```

This is working, I am seeing the agents in the namespace.
However, I am getting two pods of it.

```
kubectl get all
NAME                                                 READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/mycoolagent-gitlab-agent-v1-554f6b458c-7nn26   1/1     Running   0          43d
pod/mycoolagent-gitlab-agent-v1-554f6b458c-88v88   1/1     Running   0          43d

NAME                                                       DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/mycoolagent-gitlab-agent-v1-554f6b458c   2         2         2       43d
```

I understand they do it for reliability. However, I am in a test environment where resources are limited. I would like to just have one pod of that agent.

How to configure only one pod of the agent instead of the default two?

Comment: cant you just add `--set replicas=1` this link has a list of all the default config for the helm chart and replicas defaults as 2 https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/charts/gitlab-agent/-/blob/main/values.yaml#L11. You are already overriding some of them like image tag and config.kasadress so just overite the replicas too